# How to convert NSString to NSDictionary in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi am new to objective C, Thanks in advance for any help.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSLog(@"Notification Received: %@", userInfo);
    NSString *NSSMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];

    NotificationMessageHandler *obj = [[NotificationMessageHandler alloc] init];
    [obj handleNotificationMessage: NSSMessage]; // NSSmessage is a string to convert into JSON

}
```

I had following as NSString in NSSMessage

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "\"Status\":\"Confirm\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Type\":\"Telephone Consultation\",\"Date\":\"2015-01-05\",\"Time\":\"19:03\",\"RescheduleDate\":\"\"";
        badge = 1;
        sound = "beep.wav";
    };
}
```

Inside handleNotificationMessage, am converting NSString to JSON format

```
- (void) handleNotificationMessage : (NSString *) NSSParam
{

    if(NSSParam != nil && NSSParam != Nil)
    {

        // Parse the string
        NSLog(@"NSS Message Param %@", NSSParam);


        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                            withString:@""];
        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                                               withString:@""];


        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aps="
                                                       withString:@"\"aps\":"];
        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"alert=\""
                                                       withString:@"\"alert\":{"];
        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\";"
                                                       withString:@"\"},"];

        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"badge="
                                                       withString:@"\"badge\":"];
        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"sound="
                                                       withString:@"\"sound\":"];

        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}}\""
                                                       withString:@"}}"];

        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";"
                                                                           withString:@","];
        NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",},}"
                                                       withString:@"}}"];

        NSLog(@"NSS Message Param After Parsing %@", NSSParam);

             NSData *data = [NSSParam dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; // Here json is null
}
}
```

After parsing i had a JSON as following

```
{"aps":{"alert":{\"Status\":\"Confirm\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Type\":\"TelephoneConsultation\",\"Date\":\"2015-01-05\",\"Time\":\"20:15\",\"RescheduleDate\":\"\"},"badge":1,"sound":"beep.wav"}}
```

I had used following code to convert from NSString to JSON

```
NSData *data = [NSSParam dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; // Here json is null
```

Here json object shows null but NSData has object.
So, How to convert NSString to NSDictionary in objective c?
Please help !

Comment: 1. The first code snippet is not an NSString. 2. How are you "parsing" to JSON? 3. What are you trying to do? Please clarify your question, it is hard to understand.

Comment: I had edited my question

Comment: Don't pass nil to the error, it may contain the info you need to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you are being sent is appears to be the result of `NSDictionary`'s `description` method, e.g. what you get when you `NSLog` a dictionary. This format is *not* intended as a way of transmitting dictionary values, but as a format for people to read. If you can you should arrange for the dictionary to be send in a more suitable format, look up serialisation in the documentation.

If you can't arrange for a more suitable format then your approach will work, though it is rather inflexible as it is tied very closely to the contents of a particular message. All you've missed is fixing the escaped double-quotes. If you add:

```
NSSParam = [NSSParam stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\""
                                               withString:@"\""];
```

to the end of your pipeline then it will work.

HTH

Comment: Do you know of any piece of code that will reliably back-translate such [NSDictoinary description] back to NSDictionary? I'm trying to parse the output of an Apple command-line tool (launchctl) that has NO OTHER API. It looks exactly like the output of an NSDictionary description

Comment: @MottiShneor – I always thought Apple didn't define the output format of `description` and it was subject to change, but checking [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1410799-description?language=objc) now it says "formatted as a property list" so if you look at the plist parsing routines you might find what you need. If you don't ask a new question and someone will undoubtedly help you along. HTH

Comment: I think you got the documentation wrong. it doesn't say that the description of an NSDictionary is a plist -- rather, that the description of an NSDictionary is the same format as the description of a plist. This is very easy to see and prove.  A plist is a DTD controlled subset of XML - and in general - an XML format, while its description isn't an XML at all. (The "binary plist" is a complete different thing - an also - isn't a string at all)  Indeed a plist description looks very similar to NSDictionary description.

Comment: @MottiShneor – Maybe I wasn't clear, if the output is "formatted as a property list" then there *may* be suitable routines in the property list utilities which can parse a property list formatted as a string – I did not look myself but left that to the reader to determine, the utilities may only support XML & binary formats. Happy hunting.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code

```
NSError *error;
NSString *dictString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userInfo];//or ur dict reference..
    NSData *jsonData = [dictString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                            error:&error];
```

//(OR)..If u want to form alert value into a dictionary.Use as below

```
NSString *jsonString = [json objectForKey:@"alert"];
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 2):

What are you doing there? Look at this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

What type does userInfo have? It's an **NSDictionary**. So you have an NSDictionary, and then you go on a wild goose chase, converting that NSDictionary to an NSString, patching that string in weird and wonderful ways, trying to convert it to JSON, and trying to parse the JSON to get an **NSDictionary**.

Can you see how pointless that is? You *had* an **NSDictionary** to start with. All that code is totally pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{"aps":{"alert":{\"Status\":\"Confirm\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Type\":\"TelephoneConsultation\",\"Date\":\"2015-01-05\",\"Time\":\"19:03\",\"RescheduleDate\":\"\"},"badge" :1,"sound" :"beep.wav"}}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: After trying above format, jsonString is "{"aps":{"alert":{\"Status\":\"Confirm\",\"Location\":\"\",\"Type\":\"TelephoneConsultation\",\"Date\":\"2015-01-05\",\"Time\":\"19:52\",\"RescheduleDate\":\"\"},"badge" :1,"sound" :"beep.wav"}}";     // But still same error